# Generate JWT on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, google-api, jwt

How can I generate a JSON Web Token on Parse. There are NodeJS libraries but these are not likely to work on Parse? Since parse doesn't support NPM. I tried the client side one jsrsasign but I get errors since `navigator` is accessed. How should I generate JWT token on Parse? I need it to use [Google Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I have can use NPM modules if I "host" the Parse app on Heroku.

Comment: can you give more details on your solution? I face a similar problem. Want to do it in cloud code.